# How to use a navigation drawer in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer

First time here.

I need to use Navigation drawer for my app. But im working with Activities.
The question is, how can i select an item and redirect to an activity?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you used the Navigation Drawer Template from Android Studio, you will have a main activity with a method onNavigationItemSelected.  Implement the method to check the id of the menu item passed to it and decide which Activity to start based on the menu id.  For example:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class));          
        return true;
    }else if (id == R.id.nav_faq) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, FAQActivity.class));
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It was useful. But i have other questions now. Do you think you can help me out?

Comment: Sure.  If this answer helped you, you should accept it as the answer.  I will see how else I can help you.

Comment: Hi again. Now i want to have the Navigation Drawer on all my activities. What do i have to change?